# Limit variable in integrand and integral bounds.

Tags: integration, limits

Suppose $f$ is a function for which $\lim_{x\uparrow t}f(x) = f(t-)$ exists.

Then supposedly

\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\downarrow 0} \frac 1h\int_{t-h}^t f(s-h) \, \mathrm d s = f(t-).
\end{align*}

It looks much like the fundamental theorem of calculus, except the limit variable is also in the integrand.

How do I go about to show this?

If necessary, the assumptions on $f$ do not have to be so relaxed.

Comment: The statement is false: if $f(x) = 1$ we get $$ \lim_{h \to 0^+} \int_{t-h}^t ds = \lim_{h \to 0^+} h = 0 \neq 1 = f(t). $$ Maybe we're missing a factor of $1/h$...

Comment: Oh, yes indeed we are. I have added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ be the left-handed limit at $t$.  Changing variables, $$ \int_{t-h}^t f(s-h) ds = \int_{t-2h}^{t-h} f(s) ds. $$
By left-continuity, given $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ so that $|a - f(t-s) | < \epsilon$ for $s \in (0,\delta)$.  If $h < \delta/2$,
$$ {1 \over h}\left| \int_{t-2h}^{t-h} f(s) ds - a \right| = {1\over h}\left| \int_{t-2h}^{t-h} (f(s) - a) ds \right| \leq {1\over h} \int_{t-2h}^{t-h} |f(s) - a| ds \leq {\epsilon\over h} \int_{t-2h}^{t-h}ds = \epsilon.$$
Take $\epsilon$ to zero.

Comment: Just to clarify: what you have used with left-continuity is, given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ so that $\vert a - f(t-s)\vert < \varepsilon$ for $s\in(0,\delta)$ with $a \equiv f(t)$?

Comment: Nearly; the function may not be left-continuous, so $a$ is only the left-hand *limit*: $$ a := \lim_{s \to t^-} f(s) $$
You wrote this as $f(t-)$.

Comment: Ah, yes exactly. I meant to correct it in my comment but the limit of 5 minutes caught me. Thanks for your help!